# How to incorporate Sum and Rank function in Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to sum top 6 months oil value from the first 8 month. I am little stuck on this on how to incorporate Sum and Rank function in the SQL Code.

Here is MY SQL Code:-

```
SELECT WELL_NAME,
                Number_of_Months_on_Prod,
                OIL,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY WELL_NAME ORDER BY OIL DESC) AS RANK_OIL,
                SUM(CASE WHEN (RANK_OIL >= 1) AND (RANK_OIL) <= 6 THEN  Coalesce(BOE6, 0) ELSE 0 END) Over (PARTITION BY WELL_NAME ) as  BEST_6_OF_8_MONTH_OIL

FROM TABLE_WELL
ORDER BY WELL_NAME ;
```

I get ordered analytical function cannot be nested error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my Sample Data Set.

[image: Sample_Data]

Comment: Thank you Gordon for editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this multiple levels of window functions:

```
SELECT WELL_NAME, Number_of_Months_on_Prod, OIL,
        SUM(CASE WHEN RANK_OIL <= 6 AND SEQNUM <= 8 THEN BOE6 END) OVER (PARTITION BY WELL_NAME) AS BEST_6_OF_8_MONTH_OIL
FROM (SELECT TW.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WELL_NAME, (CASE WHEN SEQNUM <= 8 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
                                ORDER BY OIL DESC
                               ) AS RANK_OIL
      FROM (SELECT TW.*,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WELL_NAME ORDER BY OIL DESC) AS SEQNUM
            FROM TABLE_WELL TW
           ) TW
     ) TW
ORDER BY WELL_NAME ;
```